# How to give priority to layout which should be at top?

Tags: android, android-layout

In the building, tic-tac-toe grid layout occupies the upper layer and Linearlayout occupies the lower layer just below the grid layout. where the Linear layout should appear if any player wins the match. In linear layout the player who wins and a button to set the game to the starting position. So initially I set it to invisible when the game ends linear layout comes back side of grid layout. How can I make the Linear Layout on top of grid layout?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.achyu.tictactao;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//0=yellow  1=red
int currentPlayer=0;

int[] isItDone={2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

//2=yellow  1=red
int[] whoWon=new int[9];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void currentCounter(View view){

    ImageView counter= (ImageView) view;

    int tap=Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

    if(isItDone[tap]==2){

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);
        if(currentPlayer==0){

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            currentPlayer=1;
            whoWon[tap]=2;


            if((whoWon[0]==2&&whoWon[1]==2&&whoWon[2]==2)||(whoWon[3]==2&&whoWon[4]==2&&whoWon[5]==2)||
                    (whoWon[6]==2&&whoWon[7]==2&&whoWon[8]==2)||(whoWon[0]==2&&whoWon[3]==2&&whoWon[6]==2)||
                    (whoWon[1]==2&&whoWon[4]==2&&whoWon[7]==2)||(whoWon[2]==2&&whoWon[5]==2&&whoWon[8]==2)||
                    (whoWon[0]==2&&whoWon[4]==2&&whoWon[8]==2)||(whoWon[2]==2&&whoWon[4]==2&&whoWon[6]==2))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Yellow Has Won",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                TextView winnerText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winner);
                winnerText.setText("Yello Won");
                winnerText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            currentPlayer=0;

            whoWon[tap]=1;

            if((whoWon[0]==1&&whoWon[1]==1&&whoWon[2]==1)||(whoWon[3]==1&&whoWon[4]==1&&whoWon[5]==1)||
                    (whoWon[6]==1&&whoWon[7]==1&&whoWon[8]==1)||(whoWon[0]==1&&whoWon[3]==1&&whoWon[6]==1)||
                    (whoWon[1]==1&&whoWon[4]==1&&whoWon[7]==1)||(whoWon[2]==1&&whoWon[5]==1&&whoWon[8]==1)||
                    (whoWon[0]==1&&whoWon[4]==1&&whoWon[8]==1)||(whoWon[2]==1&&whoWon[4]==1&&whoWon[6]==1))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Red Has Won",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                TextView winnerText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winner);
                winnerText.setText("Red Won");
                winnerText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);
        isItDone[tap]=3;


    }
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout         
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.example.achyu.tictactao.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="587dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/orange"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="60dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/winner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            tools:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playagain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView0"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:tag="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="currentCounter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:tag="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="currentCounter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:tag="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="currentCounter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:tag="3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="currentCounter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:tag="4"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="currentCounter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:tag="5"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="currentCounter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:tag="6"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="currentCounter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:tag="7"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="currentCounter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:tag="8"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="currentCounter" />
    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nesting layouts is bad for performances, in case you care for your users experience.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your linear layout below your gridLayout in your relative layout

Comment: Thank you, yes it worked Questions shows I am a noob. its true.